# Google Sheets, apply conditional formatting based on parts of a cell

Tags: google-sheets, conditional-formatting

What I'm trying to achieve is this - In Google Sheets, I have a cell that contains numbers with a comma delimiter, for example: 
0.5,2,50,200,0,4
I want to have 6 conditional formatting rules, working on this cell.

The first rule will look at the first number (0.5), check if it's between a certain range (I'll hard code the range in the rule itself), for example check if it's between 0.2 and 0.7.

The second rule will have a different range for the 2nd number, etc.
In any case, if any of those conditional formatting is true, need to paint the entire cell in red.
I cannot use auxiliary cells, I can only use this one cell for this.

Comment: What is your question? What have you tried? Did something not work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Split the values and process them with `map()`, using `choose()` and `isbetween()`, like this:

```
=sum( 
  map( 
    split(A2, ","), sequence(1, counta(split(A2, ","))), 
    lambda( 
      value, i, 
      0 + choose( 
        i, 
        isbetween(value, 0.2, 0.7), 
        isbetween(value, 1, 1.5), 
        isbetween(value, 2, 3), 
        isbetween(value, 2, 3), 
        isbetween(value, 2, 3), 
        isbetween(value, 2, 3) 
      ) 
    ) 
  ) 
)
```

Comment: Amazing, solved it, thank you!